# Rails ActiveAdmin custom page with simple workflow for importing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have been using ActiveAdmin for one of my projects and I am quite disappointed by its learning curve. ActiveAdmin is quite good when doing simple things by the book but when it comes to something rather complicated then things are getting pretty complex.

I am trying to create this simple use-case, but I am really stuck with ActiveAdmin.
Usecase:

1. User opens custom page, ie. called Program
2. There he finds simple form with file input, which allows him to upload file
3. Once the file is submitted then user is redirected to summary page, which shows him the file content, parsed program and information about what's about to happen when he confirms the action. There will be confirm and cancel button
4. When confirm button is clicked, file is processed and result is shown

How to accomplish this simple and trivial use-case with ActiveAdmin? Can anybody please provide simple example with custom page, controller actions, appropriate partial view or whatever it takes to accomplish?

Thanks.